# What is the difference between PropertyDescriptor . PropertyType and ComponentType?

Tags: .net

What is the difference between PropertyType and ComponentType on a .NET [PropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

The docs didn't really explain

> PropertyType    When overridden in a derived class, gets the type of the property.
>
> ComponentType When overridden in a derived class, gets the type of the component this property is bound to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terms of a regular property:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

If we now look at `Foo.Bar` via `TypeDescriptor`, the component-type is `Foo`; the property-type is `Int32`. Basically, `ComponentType` is the `DeclaringType` of the property (in reflection terms). So if you are writing a custom `PropertyDescriptor` implementation, the `PropertyType` is the type of the *data*, and `ComponentType` is the expected type of the *target instance*.